# Can't remove roles from user without any error messages in Discord.JS

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to remove all roles from the sender by executing the following:

```
message.member.roles.remove(message.member.roles.cache).catch(console.error);
```

Once it's done, no error messages or anything, but the roles stay.
The bot has all the permissions it needs, and I tried restarting it multiple times.

Comment: Try adding some console.log()s around the code to make sure it's still running at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to remove all roles, and that includes `@everyone` role, which is impossible to remove. *Everyone* has it, after all.

If you list all roles (`console.log(message.member.roles.cache)`), you will notice the collection contains `@everyone` role.

Either remove roles one by one in a loop (excluding `@everyone`) or (a much better way) filter out `@everyone` role.

```
message.member.roles.remove(messabe.member.roles.cache.filter(role => role.name != @everyone));
```

Since you said there is no `console.error` message, you'd better make sure the code actually executes.